# ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier----> how can ı fix this error

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
contract CS_Shipmen {
 
    struct Shipmen {
        address walletAddress;
        string  firstName;
        string  lastName;      
    }
    Shipmen[] public shipmen;
    function addShipmen(address walletAddress, string memory firstName, string memory lastName) public{
        shipmen.push(Shipmen(
            walletAddress,
            firstName,
            lastName));
    }
    address walletAddress;
    bool check;
    modifier onlyShipmen() {    
    for (uint i = 0; i < shipmen.length; i++) {
        if(shipmen[i].walletAddress == walletAddress)
        require (checking == 1, "Only Shipmen can do a verification.");
        _;
    }
 
bool receipt;
 string yes="Your parcel has arrived";
 string no="Your parcel has not arrived yet";
function verification1(uint _verification) public returns(uint) {
    if(verification == 1){
return yes;
    }
    else if(verification == 0){
        return no;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of right curly braces "}" in your code, such as one to close your onlyShipment modifier. One to close your verification1 function and one to close your contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0; contract CS_Shipmen {

struct Shipmen {
    address walletAddress;
    string  firstName;
    string  lastName;      
}
Shipmen[] public shipmen;
function addShipmen(address walletAddress, string memory firstName, string memory lastName) public{
    shipmen.push(Shipmen(
        walletAddress,
        firstName,
        lastName));
}
address walletAddress;
bool check;
modifier onlyShipmen() {    
for (uint i = 0; i < shipmen.length; i++) {
    if(shipmen[i].walletAddress == walletAddress)
    require (checking == 1, "Only Shipmen can do a verification.");
    _;
}
}
bool receipt; 
string yes="Your parcel has arrived";
string no="Your parcel has not arrived yet"; 
function verification1(uint _verification) public returns(uint) { 
    if(verification == 1){ 
        return yes; 
    } else if(verification == 0){ 
        return no; 
    }}}
```

Bear in mind there are also a couple of undeclared variables you should address before being able to run your smart contract.